# 10 minute timestamp interval visualization for patterns using pandas for forecasting?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, forecasting

I have a data file with one column full of time stamps and I have aggregated the times in 10 minute time intervals, I am trying to visualize them to find underlying patterns of the demand. I have looked at a histogram of this information...and the heat map did not return good results. 
My information is just one column full of timestamps like this:
2017-08-28 14:37:00
I have 100,000 rows and I am trying to use pandas for forecasting, I dont know if I should use linear regression or kalman filter so far this is my visualization 
plt.figure()
df["time"].apply(lambda x: x.hour).plot.hist(bins=24) I am trying to get it more granular on a 10 minute interval time and then look at patterns and implement a forecasting technique

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what is your question precisely. From what I understood, you have a uni dimensional time-series of "demand" and you want to develop a prediction algorithm.

For your data exploration, identification of patterns", I understand you have difficulty for visualization. First, to increase the granularity of your histogram, you may want to [group your data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on a daily basis and plot an histogram with 24*6=144 bins. If you want to try more visualization, some are basics one:

- you could try a simple graph visualization as your data seems to be unidimensional
- another option is to build heatmaps with as axis the hour of the day, the day of the week (Monday, Tuesday, etc), the month of the year
- a scatterplot with as x-axis the hour between 0h and 23h, ...

You should find many [different options](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-data-visualization-with-python/).

For the prediction algorithm, you did not provide any info so we could give an hint. Try to be more specific, or have a quick search for "time series prediction"